# Is there a Golang library for parsing go sources and returning a stdlib's identifier list?

Tags: go

I'm looking for a library that should parse a go source code and returns the list of identifies related to the Go's standard library. For instance, after processing the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGUSR2)
}
```

the output should resemble something like:
`os: Signal: 1
os/signal: Notify: 1
syscall: SIGINT: 1, SIGUSR2: 1`

Comment: Asking for 3rd party libs is off-topic for StackOverflow, but what you're looking for is in Go's standard lib itself. Check out the [`go/parser`](https://golang.org/pkg/go/parser/) and [`go/ast`](https://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/) packages (as a starting point).

Answer (score 0):

(I just randomly was looking over old stuff I touched and saw this question again. I think I read the question very differently this time.)

I think this question is based on the false premise that Go’s standard library is communicating with the OS via C’s `stdlib` as most other programs do. With the exception of the optional CGo library, Go binaries do not generally link to C libraries, either statically (via .a files) or dynamically, via a .so or .dll. Go’s standard library communicates with the OS kernel via system calls implemented with interrupts and the like. There are no stdlib symbols because Go’s standard library doesn’t call C’s stdlib.

**Original answer from Oct-2018:** I’m not sure what you want to do specifically, but generally a list of tokens isn’t particularly useful. Generally you want to look at walking an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) which gives you most of the same information within a more meaningful context. For this you probably want to look at the `go/ast` and `go/parser` standard library packages should give you most of what you want.